# Format string from variable length list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list containing a variable number of items,
`list_example = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...]`

and I'd like to format it into a string as follows:
`0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...`

Currently, I'm doing this using a simple `for` loop:

```
string = ""

for i in range(len(list_example) - 1):
    string += str(list_example[i]) + "  "
string += str(list_example[-1])
```

It works well, but I feel like it must be a better (more compact) way of achieving that. If anybody knows how to do it, please, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
print(" ".join(map(str,list_example)))
```

Comment: If you don't need the resulting string, just need to `print` the values space separated, you can just do `print(*list_example)` directly. You'd only bother `map`-ing with `str` and `join`ing if you needed the final string form as a single string.